# Reading arrays from Firestore and inserting to a list in Flutter

Tags: arrays, firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

Im having problem reading arrays from Firestore, strings can be readable within future builder as below,

How ever when its time to read array field in very same document and insert in a list is just not working , actually Im not able to read the array with get method. tried [] method but always receving getting null error, List experiences = snapshot.data.get('experiences') is not working for arrays,

Is there a different method for reading arrays from firebase ? I also need to read that array put in a list and use it to list the selected data from each index to a listview  as usually we do locally with lists.

Here is the error message:

======== Exception caught by widgets library =======================================================
The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building FutureBuilder(dirty, state: _FutureBuilderState#395a0):
The method 'get' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: get("experiences")

The relevant error-causing widget was:
FutureBuilder file:///xxxxxxxx/lib/regformSummary.dart:185:45
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
#0      Object.noSuchMethod (dart:core-patch/object_patch.dart:54:5)
#1      _RegFormSummaryState.build. (package:xxxxxx/regformSummary.dart:186:94)
#2      _FutureBuilderState.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/async.dart:773:55)
#3      StatefulElement.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4612:27)
#4      ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4495:15)
...

here is working code for reading strings

```html
//under main widget builder
DocumentReference resumedata =_firestore.collection('users').doc(widget.userID).collection('resume').doc('info');
    DocumentReference userdata = _firestore.collection('users').doc(widget.userID).collection('resume').doc('personalinfo');
//

.....,
FutureBuilder(future:userdata.get(),builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<DocumentSnapshot> snapshot) {
                            if(snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done){
                              String profilepic = snapshot.data.get('profilepic');
                              String name = snapshot.data.get('name');
                              String sname = snapshot.data.get('sname');

                              return Column(
                                children: [
                                  Padding(
                                    padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10),
                                    child: CircleAvatar(
                                      minRadius: 40,
                                      maxRadius: 80,
                                      backgroundImage: NetworkImage('$profilepic'),
                                    ),
                                  ),//avatar
                                  Padding(
                                    padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10,vertical:3),
                                    child: Text(
                                      name,
                                      style: GoogleFonts.openSans(textStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.black54,fontSize: 24,fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                                    ),
                                  ),//name
                                  Padding(
                                    padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10,vertical:3),
                                    child: Text(
                                      sname,
                                      style: GoogleFonts.openSans(textStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.black54,fontSize: 24,fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                                    ),
                                  ),//sname


                                ],
                              );
                            }
                            return SizedBox();

                          }),
```

Here is the failing code

```js
DefaultTabController(
                              length:8,
                              child: SingleChildScrollView(
                                physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
                                child: Column(
                                    children: [
                                      TabBar(
                                        isScrollable: true,
                                        indicatorWeight: 4.0,
                                        indicatorColor:Colors.black38,
                                        unselectedLabelColor: Colors.black38,
                                        tabs: <Widget>[
                                          Tab(
                                            child:Text('Tecrübeler',style: TextStyle( color:
                                               colorVal
                                                )),
                                          ),
                                          Tab(
                                            child: Text('Eğitim',style: TextStyle( color: colorVal
                                               )),
                                          ),
                                          Tab(

                                            child: Text('Yabancı Dil',style: TextStyle( color: colorVal)),
                                          ),
                                          Tab(

                                            child: Text('Sertifikalar',style: TextStyle( color: colorVal)),
                                          ),
                                          Tab(

                                            child: Text('Referanslar',style: TextStyle( color:colorVal)),
                                          ),
                                          Tab(

                                            child: Text('İlgilendiği Pozisyonlar',style: TextStyle( color: colorVal)),
                                          ),
                                          Tab(

                                            child: Text('CV dosyası ve Önyazı Dosyası',style: TextStyle( color: colorVal)),
                                          ),
                                          Tab(

                                            child: Text('İletişim Bilgileri',style: TextStyle( color: colorVal)),
                                          ),
                                        ],
                                      ),
                                      SizedBox(
                                        height:MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
                                        child: TabBarView(
                                          children: <Widget>[
                                            FutureBuilder(future:resumedata.get(),builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<DocumentSnapshot> snapshot){
                                              List experiences = List.from(snapshot.data.get('experiences'));
                                              if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done){
                                                ListView.builder(
                                                    itemCount: experiences.length,
                                                    itemBuilder: (context,index){
                                                      return Padding(
                                                        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5, horizontal: 10),
                                                        child: Container(
                                                          decoration: BoxDecoration(borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20.0)), color: Colors.white, boxShadow: [
                                                            BoxShadow(color: Colors.black.withAlpha(100), blurRadius: 5.0),
                                                          ]),
                                                          child: ListTile(
                                                            isThreeLine: true,
                                                            title: Text('${experiences[index]['position']}'),
                                                            subtitle: Text('${experiences[index]['company']} - ${experiences[index]['duration']}'),

                                                          ),


                                                        ),
                                                      );
                                                    });
                                                    .....and goes on
```

and here is the data tree in Firestore

[Firestore data tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aYlN0.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You accessed snapshot.data before snapshot.connectionState was done.
Moreover, you forgot to 'return' your list view.

```
if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
    List experiences = List.from(snapshot.data.get('experiences')); // This line should be inside if block
    return ListView.builder(...); // You forgot to add 'return' here
} ....
```

This is the code inside your failing code block in your question near the end inside the future builder.

Comment: Thanks Afridi I cannot beleive Its just that , this shows I need to take a break and rest a bit :D